# Convergence of: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2nx^2}{1+n^2 x^4}$

Tags: calculus, power-series

I have to calculate the convergence of this serie:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2nx^2}{1+n^2 x^4} \space\text{being} \space x\in [1,2]$$

---

I have calculated the derivate and i know that $f_n$ has a maximum in $x=\frac{1}{\sqrt n}$, so I can know that $f_n$ is descending in $[1,2]$

It's correct to say that the serie is divergence because

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f_n(2)\leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f_n(x)$$
 and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f_n(2)$ is divergence?

Comment: You wish to find at what points of $[0,1]$ the summation converges right?

Comment: Have you tried applying Limit Comparison Test with the harmonic series?

Comment: As @SangchulLee  pointed out use limit comparison test with the harmonic series(which diverges). You will find that $x=0$ is the only positive value for which the series in question converges.

Comment: Is *divergent*, not *divergence*.

Answer (score 1):

In your interval you have

$$
\frac{2nx^2}{1+n^2 x^4} > \frac{1}{2} \frac{2nx^2}{n^2 x^4} = \frac{x^{-2}}{n} 
$$

And the latter series is diverging.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Use the integral criterion:

\begin{equation}
\int\frac{2nx^2}{1+n^2x^4}dn=\frac{\ln(1+n^2x^4)}{x^2}+constant
\end{equation}

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{2nx^2}{1+n^2 x^4} = \frac{2nx^2}{n^2 x^4 \left( 1+ \frac{1}{n^2 x^4}\right)} =  \frac{1}{n } \cdot \frac{2}{x^2\left( 1+ \frac{1}{n^2 x^4}\right)} \sim \frac{1}{n } \cdot \frac{2}{x^2}$$